# how to insert an element on a dictionary definition [Python]

Tags: python, dictionary

i would like to insert an element in dictionary definition

for example

```
d = dict()
d['something'] = "something"
print(d)
```

Ouput : {'something': 'something'}

and i want to insert something else on this definition using variables.
for example

```
d = dict()
d['something'] = "something"
var = "something else"
```

.
.
.

{'something': ('something', 'something else')}

Comment: What's stopping you from writing `d['something'] = some_variable` or `d['something'] = (var1, var2)`?

Comment: I was going to post something about using the mutablility of dictionaries but are you just asking how to create a dictionary with list values and then how to append to that value using the key?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`d = dict()
d["something"] = "something"
var = "something else"
d["something"] = (d["something"], var)`

yields

d = {'something': ('something', 'something else')}

Comment: If you need to ask clarifying questions, do it in the comments, not as an answer.

Comment: @JGreenwell I would've given that answer if the starting code was var["something"] = ("something"), but you cannot append to a string.